# Sorting multiple linked arrays in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

Consider the following list:

```
Name   Price(per kg)  Weight(in kg)

rice1       40          20
rice2       50          27
rice3       35          24
```

I want all the rice types sorted according to their value. So, I sort them.

```
new sorted price: 35 40 50
```

Now i print them and the output as below:

```
Name  Price  Weight

rice1   35    20
rice2   40    27
rice3   50    24
```

But this is not what I wanted. I wanted it to print like this:

```
Name   Price  Weight

rice3   35    24
rice1   40    20
rice2   50    27
```

so, the problem is I'm getting the the value in the sorted list but not the names and weights. I want to get sorted everything according to value.
How can i do that?

I've written the following code. But not sure what to do next.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    class treasure
    {
        public:
            std::string name[100];
            double value[100];
            double weight[100];
    };

    int itemNumber, totalWeight, i;

    treasure item;

    std::cout << "Enter total item weight(in kg): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> totalWeight;
    std::cout << std::endl <<"Enter total item number: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> itemNumber;

    //take item name, item value, item weight
    for( i = 0; i < itemNumber; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Enter item name: " << "\t" << "Enter item value(per kg): " << "\t" << "Enter item weight(in kg): " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> item.name[i] >> item.value[i] >> item.weight[i];
    }

    //sort items according to given value
    std::sort(item.value, item.value + itemNumber);

    //print sorted list
        for( i = 0; i < itemNumber; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "Item name: " << "\t" << "Item value(per kg): " << "\t" << "Item weight(in kg): " << std::endl;
        std::cout << item.name[i] << "\t\t" << item.value[i] << "\t\t\t" << item.weight[i] << std::endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use an array of structs instead of a struct of arrays. Define a comparison function for the struct.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I mean, What would be the idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure should look like this:

```
class treasure
{
    public:
        std::string name;
        double value;
        double weight;
};
```

and then you declare array of treasures:

```
treasure item[100];
```

taking items:

```
//take item name, item value, item weight
for( i = 0; i < itemNumber; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter item name: " << "\t" << "Enter item value(per kg): " << "\t" << "Enter item weight(in kg): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> item[i].name >> item[i].value >> item[i].weight;
}
```

and finally sorting:

```
std::sort(item, item + itemNumber,
    [] (auto t1, auto t2) {return t1.value < t2.value;})
```

http://ideone.com/GL3VKz

Comment: Showing this errors and 33 line is the line starting with [ ]  `||In function 'int main()':|
|33|error: expected primary-expression before '[' token|
|33|error: expected primary-expression before ']' token|
|33|warning: C++0x auto only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x|
|33|error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'|
|33|warning: C++0x auto only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x|
|33|error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'|
|36|error: expected ';' before 'for'|
|36|error: expected ';' before ')' token|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 2 warnings ===|`

Comment: Error text says directly that code shoul be compiled using C++11 standard. It enabled with -std=C++0x compilation flag in g++. Modern compilers use C++11 or C++14 by default. Here is the same axample written in C++98: http://ideone.com/WV25W7